# Using hive bucketing in select query

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a hive table bucketed on userId, My select query contains userId in where clause but hive is doing full table scan. `hive.enforce.bucketing` is true
Why don't hive take advantage of bucketing in such cases, is there any config to enable it??

Table Structure

> ```
> userId int,
> name int,
> address String,
> cell int,
> ......
> ......
> ......
> ......
> CLUSTERED BY  (userId) SORTED BY (userId) INTO 20 BUCKETS
> ```

Select query

```
select cell from <table> where userId=<userId>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cell from <table> TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET <n> OUT OF 20 ON userId) usertable where userId = <userId>
```

Comment: +1 Interesting answer! But I don't understand how this can be useful: you need to know exactly what's the content of each bucket, specifying a different <n>. Could you please provide an example where this can be useful?